# Are there mathematical methods to creating graphics?

Tags: math, graphics

I came across this page a long time ago [Steve A Baker](http://2600connection.atari.org/baker.html) And he mentions how one of the images on an earlier video game he created was done using a simple adder and math.
                                [image: Created using a 'simple adder and math']

How do you do this kind of thing? It would be really cool to create images mathematically.
I have wondered (and googled) but only found descriptions about fractals. But I don't think this is a fractal. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Procedural image generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation) is well known in the [demoscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene) community. You can refer to some of the open source demos for a variety of techniques.

Comment: Results from procedural image generation can be impressive. .kkrieger. is one of the most impressive demos I ever saw: http://www.theprodukkt.com/kkrieger

Answer (score 4):

**Just a quick example**

Suppose you have a 200x200 [RGB image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model), and you define each color component as follows:

```
 Red   = Sin[i/200]  
 Green = Tan[j/300]  
 Blue  = Sin[i j/300]
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Evolvotron](http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/share/evolvotron/gallery.htm) and other similar [evolutionary art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_art) programs basically do nothing but randomly manipulate mathematical expressions to generate images (OK user input plays a part too, which is where the "evolution" bit comes in).  Karl Sim's pioneering [paper](http://www.karlsims.com/papers/siggraph91.html) is well worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you mean by `create images mathematically`? It's pretty vague, but in order to answer your question, I'll assume you mean `create images using mathematical operations on a set of pre-defined data`.

That's pretty simple. Just make a pattern using a Python list or the alike:

```
pattern = ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o',
           'o', 'o', 'o',
           'o', 'o',
           'o']
```

Then create a canvas-like thing to handle inserts and operations on it's contents (like changing colors, etc.).

I'm not sure how to answer, since you question is kind of vague...

Comment: Have a look at the link in the question.

Comment: Oh, *this* clears it all up ;) `SB: Nope...comes from a simple adder...ain't math great?  LOL!`

Comment: Is that sarcasm? Or is it the dawn of true understanding? :D

Answer (score 1):

Quite seriously, almost all of computer graphics is mathematical.

Your sample image could be done with a modulating function.

Trigonometry, linear algebra (matrices), vectors and calculus are all used in graphics.

Comment: Any links with examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check [Aaron](http://www.kurzweilcyberart.com/).